# Aerial photos of different tide heights

Tags: uk, aerial-photography

I'm looking for aerial photos taken at different tide heights of Holy Island, Northumberland, UK. Are these available anywhere?

Comment: Could you detail what the purpose of the photos would be? You might be better off getting a tide chart and running a QGIS watershed against the heights to get an hourly tide impact.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the resolution that you require, you could try looking through the available European Space Agency satellite data https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/home